# Where do you hang your semantic information, html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantics

Well, I keep putting semantic information about **what an element means** for the page logically in the `class` attribute

```
<li class="phone-number">555-5555</li>
```

It seems to work for this dual purpose of hanging semantic information and a pointer to how to style it.

I'm not sure if this is the best idea, I'm trying to see if others have other ways of doing it.

I also started to use a hidden input:

```
<li>555-5555 <input class="semantics" type="hidden" value="phone-number" /></li>
```

inside an element, so with jQuery, I can retrieve additional information about the element using

```
li.find( '.semantics' ).val()
```

To get an element's semantics from JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hang my semantics by manuals and examples at [microformats.org](http://microformats.org). And what about styling - you can use multiple classes for html elements.
In jQuery you can use `$('.phone-number').html()` for your first example.

Comment: I think the microformats are conserned to be a standard to hold semantics in html.

Answer (score 2):

1. Either you try XML, and use for
   example XSLT for the presentation,
2. or HTML with a custom DTD
3. or HTML 5 and the
   [data-attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html) (3.2.1
   Semantics)

Comment: The data attribute setup is awesome!

Comment: Do you really think going the XSLT route is a good choice, considering also maintenence by other developers (new requirement: must know XSLT?)
Is going through the hassle of a custom DTD worthwhile at all, and again, the maintenance issue?

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the semantics itself... IDs and classes would normally suffice for this purposes.

But adding markup such as hidden fields for this purpose sounds like a terrible idea to me.

Maybe if you shared your actual needs we could share a better way to do it.